# Addition of integers from two different list of lists of unicode object and integer

Tags: python, list, unicode, addition

I have a list of lists of unicode object and integer as follows. There are two such lists and I want to add the integer values of both these lists if the unicode objects(date&time) match

```
list1 = [ [u'2015-01-01T05:00:00.000Z', 58],[u'2015-01-01T05:15:00.000Z', 57],[u'2015-01-01T05:30:00.000Z', 55],
[u'2015-01-01T05:45:00.000Z', 54] ]

list2 = [ [u'2015-01-01T05:00:00.000Z', 65],[u'2015-01-01T05:15:00.000Z', 67],[u'2015-01-01T05:30:00.000Z', 61],
[u'2015-01-01T05:45:00.000Z', 74] ]
```

I created a dictionary object with date&time as a key and integer as a value. I tried to add the integers if the key matches. However, a dictionary does not give me date&time in order when I try to save the output in a CSV. I am fairly new to python and I am sure there are more sophisticated ways to do this.

Comment: If you're new to Python, consider switching to Python 3 instead of learning the old version 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can `sort` the `keys` like so:

```
for key in sorted(dict.keys()):
   #keys will now appear in a sorted way
```

Comment: Can you please also tell me how can I create a list of dictionaries such that each dictionary is a separate day of the year. I will be iterating through a dictionary which contains an entire years data as mentioned above with datetime as key and integer as value